# Room resources not listing in Calendar for OSX

Tags: mac-osx, calendar, exchange-2013, mailbox

I have set up a Room Resource mailbox on Exchange 2013 and am trying to get the calendar to display in OSX's calendar app. I have granted free/busy permissions to Group A and set the default to none and anonymous to none.

User A who is a member of Group A on OSX 10.8.5 can see the room resources displayed in Calendar similar to [here](http://one.utsa.edu/sites/oit/OITConnect/mac/Pages/exchange_shared_calendars.aspx).

User B who is also a member of Group A on OSX 10.8.5 does not get a list in Calendar. User B can access the calendar using Outlook 2011.

Users C through Z are also like User B.

Is there some special check box I am missing to get it working for Users B through Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the contacts syncing was not checked. Once we checked contacts syncing for the exchange account, Users B-Z can see the room listings.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had luck with Apple's software (iCal, Calendar, iOS) working well with Rooms in MS Exchange (any version.) However, you could try the steps outlined [HERE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76679/how-do-i-create-a-resource-room-in-exchange-so-it-can-be-viewed-like-a-calenda). MS Outlook 2011 usually works okay, though.